# MSSql Server messages blow up event log

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, event-viewer

My event viewer is blown up by tons of SQLSERVER messages. there is a new message approximately every second. The messages vary and are of different structures. Here are a few examples:

```
**MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS**
Category:   Server
Message:    
System Manufacturer: 'LENOVO', System Model: '4004C5G'.


**MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS**
Category:   Server
Message:    
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

I'm using a local database file on the machine (MDB) which is being attached during runtime from within a .NET application to the local SQL instance.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how can i turn it off?

Comment: When you debug your code, do you get any exceptions? Can you post the event viewer messages (at least a sample)?

Comment: Message: text is empty?